# How to escape colons in JS variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I think this is the problem

I have this part here which I think is the problem. A function before it parses a JSON page (json url with private api key is defined before the block of code) and needs to get temperature from the "00:00:00" part

```
     message.channel.send('Weather temperature at 00:00:00 is : ' +data.00:00:00.temperature+ '.');
```

This is the error

```
    C:\Users\HUM0014\Desktop\serveruptime\serverandweather.js:102
    console.log('Weather temperature at 00:00:00 is : ' +data.00:00:00.temperature+ '.');
                                                                   ^^^^

    SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

My thoughts are that the colons are breaking it, but I'm extremely new to JS so I'm not 100% sure

The full code is this

```
    var url = 'JSON URL HERE';
    var weathercommand = '/weather';

    client.on('message', message => {
        if(message.channel.id !== "588541716961951756") return;
        if(message.author.bot) return;
        if (message.content === weathercommand) {
    'use strict';


    request.get({
        url: url,
        json: true,
        headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
      }, (err, res, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error:', err);
        } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
          console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
        } else {
          // data is already parsed as JSON:
          console.log(data.location.name);
          console.log('Weather temperature at 00:00:00 is : ' +data.00:00:00.temperature+ '.');
          //message.channel.send('Weather location is : ' +data.location.name+ '.'); //this works perfectly fine
         // message.channel.send('Weather temperature at 00:00:00 is : ' +data.00:00:00.temperature+ '.');

        }})}});
```

Answer (score 1):

For object keys that have certain characters that aren't valid in identifiers, you will need to access them with [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) instead of [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation).

eg: `data['00:00:00'].temperature`

Comment: console.log('Weather temperature at 00:00:00 is : ' +data['00:00:00']temperature+ '.');
                                                                              ^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. You still need .temperature or ['temperature'] at the end. Make sure to check the article I sent in my post.